# Why all the MAC addresses on my network is the same?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, cmd.exe, ethernet, arp

When I write `arp -a` on CMD I found all the devices that connected to me network. But the problem is they all have the same MAC addresses?

How can I get the MAC addresses for all of them? Is there any tool to let me see them?

```
C:\Users\hp>arp -a

Interface: 192.0.8.68 --- 0xa
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.0.0.0             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.1             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.2             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.3             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.4             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.5             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.6             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.7             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.8             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.9             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.10            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.11            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.12            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.13            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.14            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.15            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.16            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.17            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.18            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.19            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.20            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.21            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.22            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.23            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.24            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.25            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.26            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.27            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.28            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.29            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.30            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.31            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.32            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.33            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.34            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.35            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.36            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.37            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.38            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.39            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.40            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.41            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.42            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.43            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.44            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.45            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.46            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.47            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.48            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.49            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.50            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.51            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.52            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.53            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.54            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.55            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.56            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.57            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.58            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.59            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.60            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.61            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.62            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.63            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.64            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.65            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.66            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.67            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.68            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.69            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.70            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.71            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.72            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.73            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.74            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.75            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.76            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.77            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.78            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.79            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.80            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.81            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.82            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.83            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.84            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.85            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.86            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.87            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.88            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.89            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.90            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.91            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.92            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.93            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.94            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.95            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.96            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.97            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.98            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.99            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.100           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.101           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.102           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.103           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.104           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.105           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.106           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.107           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.108           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.109           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.110           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.111           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.112           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.113           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.114           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.115           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.116           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.117           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.118           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.119           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.120           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.121           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.122           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.123           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.124           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.125           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.126           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.127           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.128           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.129           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.130           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.131           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.132           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.133           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.134           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.135           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.136           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.137           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.138           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.139           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.140           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.141           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.142           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.143           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.144           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.145           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.146           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.147           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.148           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.149           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.150           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.151           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.152           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.153           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.154           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.155           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.156           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.157           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.158           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.159           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.160           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.161           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.162           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.163           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.164           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.165           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.166           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.167           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.168           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.169           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.170           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.171           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.172           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.173           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.174           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.175           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.176           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.177           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.178           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.179           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.180           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.181           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.182           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.183           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.184           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.185           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.186           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.187           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.188           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.189           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.190           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.191           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.192           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.193           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.194           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.195           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.196           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.197           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.198           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.199           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.200           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.201           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.202           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.203           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.204           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.205           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.206           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.207           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.208           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.209           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.210           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.211           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.212           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.213           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.214           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.215           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.216           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.217           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.218           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.219           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.220           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.221           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.222           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.223           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.224           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.225           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.226           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.227           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.228           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.229           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.230           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.231           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.232           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.233           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.234           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.235           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.236           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.237           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.238           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.239           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.240           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.241           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.242           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.243           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.244           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.245           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.246           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.247           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.248           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.249           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.250           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.251           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.252           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.253           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.254           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.0.255           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.0             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.1             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.2             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.3             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.4             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.5             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.6             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.7             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.8             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.9             00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.10            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.11            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.12            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.13            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.14            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.15            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.16            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.17            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.18            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.19            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.20            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.21            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.22            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.23            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.24            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.25            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.26            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.27            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.28            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.29            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.30            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.31            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.32            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.33            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.34            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.35            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.36            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.37            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.38            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.39            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.40            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.41            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.42            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.43            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.44            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.45            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.46            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.47            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.48            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.49            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.50            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.51            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.52            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.53            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.54            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.55            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.56            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.57            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.58            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.59            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.60            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.61            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.62            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.63            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.64            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.65            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.66            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.67            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.68            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.69            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.70            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.71            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.72            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.73            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.74            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.75            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.76            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.77            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.78            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.79            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.80            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.81            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.82            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.83            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.84            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.85            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.86            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.87            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.88            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.89            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.90            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.91            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.92            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.93            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.94            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.95            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.96            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.97            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.98            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.99            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.100           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.101           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.102           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.103           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.104           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.105           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.106           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.107           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.108           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.109           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.110           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.111           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.112           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.113           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.114           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.115           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.116           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.117           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.118           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.119           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.120           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.121           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.122           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.123           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.124           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.125           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.126           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.127           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.128           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.129           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.130           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.131           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.132           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.133           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.134           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.135           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.136           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.137           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.138           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.139           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.140           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.141           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.142           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.143           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.144           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.145           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.146           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.147           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.148           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.149           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.150           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.151           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.152           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.153           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.154           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.155           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.156           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.157           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.158           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.159           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.160           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.161           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.162           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.163           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.164           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.165           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.1.166           00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.73.2            00-00-00-00-20-40     dynamic
  192.0.255.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.2.0.252           01-00-5e-02-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

C:\Users\hp>
```

the output of `route -n` :

```
C:\Users\hp>route -n

Manipulates network routing tables.

ROUTE [-f] [-p] [-4|-6] command [destination]
                  [MASK netmask]  [gateway] [METRIC metric]  [IF interface]

  -f           Clears the routing tables of all gateway entries.  If this is
               used in conjunction with one of the commands, the tables are
               cleared prior to running the command.

  -p           When used with the ADD command, makes a route persistent across
               boots of the system. By default, routes are not preserved
               when the system is restarted. Ignored for all other commands,
               which always affect the appropriate persistent routes.

  -4           Force using IPv4.

  -6           Force using IPv6.

  command      One of these:
                 PRINT     Prints  a route
                 ADD       Adds    a route
                 DELETE    Deletes a route
                 CHANGE    Modifies an existing route
  destination  Specifies the host.
  MASK         Specifies that the next parameter is the 'netmask' value.
  netmask      Specifies a subnet mask value for this route entry.
               If not specified, it defaults to 255.255.255.255.
  gateway      Specifies gateway.
  interface    the interface number for the specified route.
  METRIC       specifies the metric, ie. cost for the destination.

All symbolic names used for destination are looked up in the network database
file NETWORKS. The symbolic names for gateway are looked up in the host name
database file HOSTS.

If the command is PRINT or DELETE. Destination or gateway can be a wildcard,
(wildcard is specified as a star '*'), or the gateway argument may be omitted.

If Dest contains a * or ?, it is treated as a shell pattern, and only
matching destination routes are printed. The '*' matches any string,
and '?' matches any one char. Examples: 157.*.1, 157.*, 127.*, *224*.

Pattern match is only allowed in PRINT command.
Diagnostic Notes:
    Invalid MASK generates an error, that is when (DEST & MASK) != DEST.
    Example> route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 155.0.0.0 157.55.80.1 IF 1
             The route addition failed: The specified mask parameter is invalid. (Destination & Mask) != Destination.

Examples:

    > route PRINT
    > route PRINT -4
    > route PRINT -6
    > route PRINT 157*          .... Only prints those matching 157*

    > route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
             destination^      ^mask      ^gateway     metric^    ^
                                                         Interface^
      If IF is not given, it tries to find the best interface for a given
      gateway.
    > route ADD 3ffe::/32 3ffe::1

    > route CHANGE 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 157.55.80.5 METRIC 2 IF 2

      CHANGE is used to modify gateway and/or metric only.

    > route DELETE 157.0.0.0
    > route DELETE 3ffe::/32

C:\Users\hp>
```

Comment: Are you using any Wi-Fi repeater/extender?

Comment: I'm using Ethernet

Comment: @AdmeralSemo699 If you are not willing to do even a quick search, then no one will help you...

Comment: Are those *other* devices using any wi-fi repeater/extender?

Comment: And also, what kind of Ethernet network in general? Home? Office? University? Library?

Comment: Please include the output for `arp -a` in your post.

Comment: @u1686_grawity it's ethernet

Comment: @u1686_grawity actually a wifi but I removed the ethernet cable from the network point and connected to my pc so it ethernet for me and for others it's wifi from the point on the street !

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes it has repeater/extender

Comment: @John I used Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech) but the MAC address is empty !

Comment: Something is wrong with your OS that needs repairing

Comment: Are all these devices identical? Do they work correctly with the computer? What are these devices anyway?

Comment: It is a strange IP address range for the assumption it being local. I would have assumed it should be some form of 192.168.x.x. It looks like there may be some for of proxy arp going on & your router is responding with as the best placed device to handle all those destination which would happen to be remote, not local. Are you sure it is somewhere under 192.0.x.x rather than 192.168.x.x?

Comment: @Bib it's 192.0.0.1

Comment: Then publish the output of `ip addr` & `route -n`.

Comment: i added the output of `route -n` but the output of `ip addr` is :
` C:\Users\hp>192.0.0.1
'192.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\hp> `

Comment: Okay, so it's a Windows rather than *nix system, so it's `route print` & `ipconfig` or is it `ipconfig -a`. Telling us what the os is helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking but I think I might.

Ping the address first so it is sitting in the arp cache.

```
ping 192.168.1.1
arp -a
```

Look through the results.. usually the first interface.  I use findstr to narrow it down.

```
C:\Users\dashiznit>ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1
Packets: flargle bargle... etc etc

C:\Users\dashiznit>arp -a|findstr 192.168.1.1

Interface: 192.168.1.69 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic <-- here
```

Comment: yes it show's like you but the Internet Address is is deferent but all the Physical Address are the same !!!! all of them is 00-00-00-00-20-40